# How to move closed loop pole to meet the design requirements for settling time and overshoot?

Tags: control, root-locus

I have tried adding a lead compensator as shown in the second image however am now confused as to how to move the closed loop pole on the right into the feasible region. The first image shows the poles and zeros in my system which are fixed. Any ideas on how to move this closed loop pole into the feasible region would be greatly appreciated! Or is it possible for me to achieve the design requirements with this closed loop pole remaining in the unfeasible region?

Many thanks
[image]

Comment: And here's one from Picasso's early period called "blurred triangles of pale yellow and white".

Comment: Ah yes, good point, I have reuploaded a better image.

Comment: Which poles are you trying to move into the feasible (white) region ? From your second image, three of the four poles are in the feasible (white) region.